# Button not absolutely positioned in section

Tags: html, css, positioning

These buttons are supposed to be absolutely positioned within the `.gallery`, but for some reason, when I expand the viewport, they stretch outside of the gallery and are positioned to the viewport. Am I missing something here?

**HTML:**

```
<section class="gallery">
  <div>
    <a href="http://www.cnn.com">
      <img src="/img/gallery-img-1.jpg" alt="Cover of lookbook">
     </a>
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com"><img src="/img/gallery-img-1.jpg" alt="Cover of lookbook"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com"><img src="/img/gallery-img-2.jpg" alt="Some beautiful necklaces"></a></li>
    <li><a href="http://www.cnn.com"><img src="/img/gallery-img-3.jpg" alt="More beautiful necklaces"></a></li>
  </ul>
  <button class="arrow leftArrow">&lt;</button>
  <button class="arrow rightArrow">&gt;</button>
</section>
```

**CSS:**

```
.gallery {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
}

.gallery div, .gallery li:not(:first-child) {
  display: none;
}

.arrow {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  font-size: 2em;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.leftArrow {
  top: 40%;
  left: 5%;
}

.rightArrow {
  top: 40%;
  right: 5%;
}
```

Comment: is this issue happening in all browsers?

Comment: Can't recreate this with code you provided [here's fiddle of your code](http://jsfiddle.net/knfa2fw5/)- can you create a fiddle that shows the issue?

Comment: I've only checked in Chrome and IE (latest), and it is happening in both of those.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/odf2qthz/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed it. All I had to do was add `display: inline-block;` to the `.gallery` and that kept the boundries of the gallery from stretching beyond the width of the images. Thanks for your help, everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Change the width on your image from `max-width` to `width:100%`

```
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

The issue was occurring when the viewport became larger than the image size.  Since you had set `max-width: 100%` the image was being constrained.  The arrow was positioned properly, but the image stopped expanding to fill the viewport.

Comment: It's a responsive image gallery, so I want to keep the min-width. If the images are smaller than the viewport, I don't want them to keep stretching until they get pixelated.

Comment: Understood - though you should use images with resolution high enough to work in various screen sizes.

Comment: I want to create this plugin for my Github repository, so I can't trust that anyone who uses it will use appropriately sized images, you know?